# Complex Chebyshev Polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis, numerical-methods, chebyshev-polynomials

Chebyshev Polynomials can be used to compute a very nearly minimax polynomial approximation of an analytic function on $[-1,1]$.  Is there a complex analog that can compute a nearly minimax polynomial for a holomorphic function on the unit disc?

Comment: There is a natural and much-studied complex analog: the monic polynomial of smallest supremum on a given compact set. E.g., [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1404.3340) and references there. For the unit disk this would be simply $z^n$. I don't know about using them to approximate a holomorphic function.

Comment: Thanks, that is definitely in the direction of what I am looking for.